# Getting the maximum value from strings

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have option strings in WordPress like the following:

```
$option[max_slider_function_1];
$option[max_slider_function_2];
$option[max_slider_function_3];
$option[max_slider_function_4];
$option[max_slider_function_5];

...............................

$option[max_slider_function_15];
```

I want the maximum maximum  which in this case is 15.

**Note**

The string `$option[max_slider_function_<number>]` can extend upto a very long number.

Any help please?

Comment: is there anything you tried? SO is not a 'write my code' site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array (`usort()`) with a call back to sort the array accordingly first and then get the last value (`end()`).

```
function compare_value($a, $b)
{
    $a = end(explode('_', $a));
    $b = end(explode('_', $b));
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($option , "compare_value");
$max = end($option);
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/408958)

Comment: There are no leading zeros, so 9 would come after 15 for example.

Comment: @HenryTK Missed that one. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use php functions to `ksort` array keys then use end function to get the last element

```
ksort($option);
echo end($option);
```